# How can I match a specific parameter from URL?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string *(which is the value of href attribute)* like this:

```
var url = '/myweb/search?s=islamic_sources&q=test';
```

It also sometimes looks like these:

```
url = '/myweb/search?q=test';
url = '/myweb/search?q=test&g=sth';
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/usG0Aa/2)

```
^[^?]+.*?&?q=([^$|&]+)
```

is what I've tried so far, and I need to match `test` in those three lines. But sadly seems `$` doesn't mean end of line in my pattern. How can I fix it?

Comment: It is not quite clear why you chose this regex. Try [`\bq=([^&]+)(?!.*\?)`](https://regex101.com/r/xuRvUs/1) (note `\n` added in the demo since it is a multiline string). The `(?!.*\?)` here will fail all matches outside a query string.

Comment: Regex is tricky, but here's how someone else on SO accesses the query variables in a similarly formatted string, I hope it helps!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: follow this - https://gist.github.com/marmeladze/f693501707940b1ea1af433c327800a9

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your pattern [works as well](https://regex101.com/r/xuRvUs/2). But do you know why it doesn't work in [JS](https://jsfiddle.net/5nL7psof/) ? *(it doesn't work when I remove `\n` either)*

Comment: What a strange piece of code... [Here is the correct one](https://jsfiddle.net/5nL7psof/2/) (without error checking).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your code returns the matched thing. but I want that url with a new value instead of matched thing.

Comment: Then use [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/5nL7psof/3/).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, now that's correct. But that's odd, because your code is exactly the same as mine. Just I've used `\K` in the pattern and removed `q=` in the substitution.

Comment: Yes, but JavaScript regex engine does not support the PCRE operator `\K`

Comment: Oh ..! I see now

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
url.match(/q=([^&]*)/)
```

This will return an array. If not empty, `test` will be at index 1.

```js
var url1 = '/myweb/search?s=islamic_sources&q=test';
var url2 = '/myweb/search?q=test';
var url3 = '/myweb/search?q=test&g=sth';

console.log(url1.match(/q=([^&]*)/)[1]);
console.log(url2.match(/q=([^&]*)/)[1]);
console.log(url3.match(/q=([^&]*)/)[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

the regex is `/q=[^&]+/` and execute it in the `url`, then take first match, split it on `=`, then take second part.

I created it as a function below.

```js
var url1 = '/myweb/search?s=islamic_sources&q=test';
var url2 = '/myweb/search?q=test';
var url3 = '/myweb/search?q=test&g=sth';

function retMatch(url){
  var re=/q=[^&]+/;
  return re.exec(url1)[0].split('=')[1];
}
console.log(retMatch(url1));
console.log(retMatch(url2));
console.log(retMatch(url3));
```